# Div aparecer uma unica vez

Tags: jquery, script, cookies, blogger

Como fazer para uma Div (não uma pop-up, e sim mais como uma tela de proteção) aparecer uma unica vez a cada 6 horas usando JQuery e Cookies? Não posso usar PHP porque a plataforma que estou utilizando é o Blogger e ela não permite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage), que tem comportamento parecido com o cookie

O código abaixo irá criar um `localStorage` com o valor em milissegundos da hora atual + 6 horas pra frente. A cada carregamento da página, o código irá subtrair o tempo armazenado no `localStorage` pelo valor em milissegundos da hora atual; se o resultado for negativo, significa que as 6 horas já se passaram desde a criação do `localStorage` e irá mostrar a `div`, e na mesma hora renovar o `localStorage` com mais 6 horas pra frente.

Este seria um exemplo da `div`, que deve ter inicialmente `display: none;`:

```
<div id="tela" style="display: none; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: red;">
   Só irá aparecer novamente após 6 horas
</div>
```

Este é o código:

```
function criaCookie(){
   var data_at = new Date();
   var data_6h = new Date(data_at);

   var data_6h = data_6h.setHours(data_at.getHours()+6);

   localStorage.protetor = data_6h;
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
   if(localStorage.getItem("protetor") === null){

      criaCookie();
      $('#tela').show();

   }else{

      var tempo_fim = localStorage.protetor;

      var data_at = new Date();
      var data_at = data_at.setHours(data_at.getHours());
      var tempo = tempo_fim - data_at;

      if(tempo <= 0){
         localStorage.removeItem("protetor");
         criaCookie();
         $('#tela').show();
      }

   }

});
```

### Exemplo funcional de 1 minuto para testar

Para fim de teste, este exemplo mostra que a `div` só irá aparecer a cada 1 minuto. Execute o código e execute novamente depois de uns segundos. Na primeira execução, a `div` será exibida, na segunda execução, não mais. Aguarde 1 minuto e execute novamente, e a `div` será exibida.

**[Teste no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x10okxdL/)**

Comment: huahuahuahua,exemplo funcional!!!!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo ahah... Vou patentear: `exemplo funcional©`. rsrsrs

Comment: vou ter que pagar royalties??

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo claro que não, eu te forneço uma licença de 30 dias para avaliação rs

Comment: hahahahaha, vou pensar

Comment: Cara eu ache muito interessante seu exemplo, parabéns mas também consegui implementar um botão, de confirmação caso o usuário queira fechar a Div estando ciente disso, no caso oque eu fiz ficou assim, removi o criaCookie(); e inseri dentro de uma função nova, dentro dessa função ela da o display none na div e da o retorno para o criaCookie(); e é claro, o botão esta dentro da div

Comment: @JoãoVictor Fica legal tb do jeito que vc fez. Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcá-la ✓. Abs!